# iPhone: offset with compass heading values between landscape right and landscape left

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, cllocationmanager, compass-geolocation

To be clear my problem is not reading the heading values in landscape right or left. It works fine I'm using a location manager and subtract 90° to read the heading value in landscape right and 270° in landscape left, by default the device is always considered in Portrait mode, that is why we have to make this adjustments.

I recently developed a location-based augmented reality app and what I'm experiencing is, there is always an offset with the heading values between landscape right and left. I tested "on field", the offset is approximately 12°.

I want this app to be as accurate as possible, I mean since we rely on sensor data here and this is the first release, less than 10° is acceptable (even 15° in the worst cases). But if we add to the existing error an offset of 12° it is quite annoying.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? I would like to have one even if I cannot fix it right now. So now I'm trying to "fix" this by adding 12° to landscape left, or maybe I should rather subtract 12° to landscape right, well I don't know!

Any experiences on this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My experience is that the compass is not very good, especially in landscape view. I would NOT subtract 12° in one view since the difference might something else on another device. I suggest that you test on one or two other iPhones before proceeding.

Also, are you setting the view of the LocationManager?

```
CLLocationManager *compassManager;
compassManager.headingOrientation =CLDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, appreciate it!

In fact I didn't set this property, so now using it prevents me of doing the trick by subtracting 90° or 270°, the code is cleaner now.

Ok I have to admit I can't do more about the compass accuracy, and it would be much wiser to avoid adding 12° on other devices. After the release of this app, I'm planning on developing a version 2.0 using Core Motion for the heading, and exploit the sample project pARk from Apple. It can't be worse :)

Comment: +1 for the compassManager.headingOrientation =CLDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft; - helped me out

Comment: What about the adjustments when the iPhone is in the middle of Portrait and Landscape?

Answer (score 6):

I also just ran into this issue and there is a difference between LandscapeLeft, landscapeRight and Portrait.  Thanks to Sten's reply and the Swift code below fixed the issue.

> ```
> override func willRotateToInterfaceOrientation(toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: NSTimeInterval) {
>     var text=""
>     switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation{
>     case .Portrait:
>         text="Portrait"
>         locationManager.headingOrientation = CLDeviceOrientation.Portrait
>     case .PortraitUpsideDown:
>         text="PortraitUpsideDown"
>         locationManager.headingOrientation = CLDeviceOrientation.Portrait
>     case .LandscapeLeft:
>         text="LandscapeLeft"
>         locationManager.headingOrientation = CLDeviceOrientation.LandscapeLeft
>     case .LandscapeRight:
>         text="LandscapeRight"
>         locationManager.headingOrientation = CLDeviceOrientation.LandscapeRight
>     default:
>         text="Another"
>     }
>     NSLog("You have moved: \(text)")
> ```

```
}
```

Comment: But will the method run only if `info.plist` has all orientations selected?